Evaluate $\int_{\ -\infty\ }^{\infty\ }\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx+2\int_{\ -1}^1\ \frac{x^5-x^3}{1+x^5}dx$
Evaluate $\int_{\ -\infty\ }^{\infty\ }\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx+2\int_{\ -1}^1\ \frac{x^5-x^3}{1+x^5}dx$.
One thing that I have noticed is that it's not possible to evaluate the integrals separately (at least my elementary ways). The denominator is also same, I guess I need to make the limits same of both integrals, but I am not able to do that.
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

What substitutions have you tried to make the limits same?

@whatamidoing x to 1/x is the famous substitution...but it's doing nothing

Utilize the cancellation below
\begin{align}
&\int_{\ -\infty\ }^{\infty\ }\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx+2\int_{\ -1}^1\ \frac{x^5-x^3}{1+x^5}dx\\
= &\int_{\ -\infty\ }^{\infty\ }\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx+2\int_{\ -1}^1\ \bigg( 1- \frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}\bigg)dx\\ 
=&\ 4 +\int_{-\infty}^{-1 }\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}\overset{x\to \frac1x}{dx}
 + \int^{\infty }_{1}\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5} \overset{x\to \frac1x}{dx}\\
&\>\>\>\>\> - \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx
- \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x^3}{1+x^5}dx=4
\end{align}
